# Html onclick href with arguments to program/script

Tags: javascript, html

I currently building a local webpage which can trigger the restart services by clicking on the button on this webpage to launch it. Is it possible to pass value(service A,service B,service C) from the html restart button to inside the powershell script?

Note: Restart button will href to the script path to trigger it. For localhost usage only.

```
  <a href="path to powershell script"><button onclick="confirm('Restart the server?')">Restart</button></a>
```

[image]

Comment: Bind onclick event on `a` rather than `button`

Comment: I see no powershell script here. You should be able to launch it as a mandatory param but no idea what you are doing, context please.

Comment: The powershell is the restart services script which required to input the server name in order to remote restart the services. Generally, what I had done was using href to launch a script which preconfigured with the server name(No1 restart service A, No2 restart service B, No3 restart service C), in other meaning I needed to duplicate the script with different filename and different pre-configured server name inside the script in order to execute it through the html button. Example, refer the picture, restart button 1 will href to serviceA.ps1, button 2 href to serviceB.ps1 and so on.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to start a shell script from a website. Linking to the script will result in the browser asking to download it or show the contents. You need a server that processes the button click and run the respective shell script.

Comment: @Capricorn Hi, fyi, yes the browser will prompt "Do you want to open or save <filename.ps1> from <PC Name>?", upon click on the open, the script can be executed, so it's possible to start a ps script from a webpage.